# Stitching several canvas images together and saving them as a file?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I have a bunch of pictures I upload via Javascript into some Canvas elements. 
I then want to stitch them together and save them as a new image.

I've uploaded them and got them in Canvas, but I can't figure out how to stitch them together and save them.

Ideas?

Comment: Please post the relevant code you have so far showing how you store your images and please elaborate on *how* you want the images stitched together (horizontally, vertically, tiled..). Where in your code did the problem occur?

Comment: I haven't done it yet. So far each Canvas item is held in it's own canvas tag specified by row and column value. I want to stick them tiled. So if you imagine a 3x3 grid. I'd want the rows stitched horizontally, then the 3 rows stitched one on top of the other.

Comment: Somwething like [this](http://abdiassoftware.com/easycanvas/samples/sample_loadimages.html) ?

Comment: Wow that's pretty close, but I want to be able to merge them into one canvas so I can save it as an image.

Comment: They are merged into a canvas in that demo. If you're ok with a library I can make an example/answer for it.

Comment: Yeah that'd be great. In that demo I can't save the image..

Comment: I didn't add it for that demo, but I will show how in the answer. 1 sec..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref. the comments: for this answer to work you need to use my library easyCanvasJS (available on [GitHub](https://github.com/AbdiasSoftware/easyCanvasJS) and [here](http://easyCanvasJS.com/)). It's a free library/MIT licensed.

### [Online demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/dg3P9/)

```
/// create a new instance of easyCanvas using canvas with id "demo"
var ez = new easyCanvas('demo'),

    /// define the image URLs
    urls = ['http://img1.jpg',
            'http://img2.jpg',
            ...etc...
    ];

/// Use the built-in loader to load all the images
ez.loadImages(urls, done);
    
/// draw all images that was loaded
function done(e) {

    var i, t, x = 0, y = 0,
        w = ez.width * 0.333,  /// grid 3x3 assuming 9 images
        h = ez.height * 0.333,
        count = 0;

    /// fill canvas with a grid of the images
    for(i = 0; i < e.images.length; i++) {

        /// if image was successfully loaded image will not be null
        if (e.images[i] !== null) {
            ez.ctx.drawImage(e.images[i], x, y, w, h);
            count++;

            /// move to next spot for next image
            if (((i + 1) % 3) === 0) {
                x = 0;
                y += h;
            } else x += w;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Now all the images should have loaded and are drawn in a 3x3 grid on a single canvas.

To save that canvas as an image simply use:

```
ez.download('filename.png');
```

In the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/dg3P9/) I added a download button below the canvas.

If you want to incorporate progress bar please see the [original sample here](http://abdiassoftware.com/easycanvas/samples/sample_loadimages.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think I'd prefer a manual solution without a library. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @ChrisG err, why didn't you say that *before* I made the example (as I asked you in advance)... most of the code above is not related to the lib but to tile the image. Anyways..

Comment: I still appreciate it but I changed my mind. Thank you regardless.